# SQL Conditional Join and new variable creation

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have two tables I will call T1 and T2. T1 has 3 variables called var1 var2 and var3 and T2 has one variable called X and 3 id variables for var1, var2, and var3. I need to join T1 to T2 with 3 different join conditions to create 3 different variables.

Something like:

```
`Select*
 From t1
    left join t2 on case
    when t1.var1=t2.var1_ID then first_name=x
    when t1.var2=t2.var2_id then last_name=x
    when t1.var3=t2.var3_id then group=x
    else null
end
`
```

Comment: So where are you stuck? Nowhere in your problem description is a question for help with something.

Comment: The code I posted does not work so I need help finding a sql query with the same logic, but working sql code. I'm not even sure how to search for my issue because it is not just conditional joining, but i need to create 3 new variables in the conditional join and my sql skills are mediocre at best.  I know I am not explaining this well, but I'm not really sure how to describe my issue any better.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work for you :

```
`Select *
 From t1
    left join t2 on 
    1 = case
    when t1.var1=t2.var1_ID then 
        case when first_name=x then 1 else 0 end else 1 end and
    1 = case 
    when t1.var2=t2.var2_id then 
        case when last_name=x then 1 else 0 end else 1 end and
    1 = case 
    when t1.var3=t2.var3_id then 
        case when group=x then 1 else 0 end else 1 end 
end
```